# Cheap 100% Debian compatible ultrabooks

Tags: linux, debian, devices

I'm looking for relatively cheap ultrabooks with 100% Debian compatible features.

I have several ultrabooks on my list but they contain some additional features which i don't need (additional graphic card or 'beats' studio). When reading the reviews everyone mention that there are 'minor' issues with running linux on them - mute indicator.

Comment: In general, shopping questions are considered off-topic/not answerable on Unix & Linux SE.

Comment: So this isn't a place where you ask for a help regarding linux?

Comment: When I got my brand-new netbook that came out the month I bought it, I had a very hard time getting Linux, especially Debian running, mainly because of driver issues. Debian

Comment: FYI: The general policy ChrisDown refers to is from the blog post [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). Different SE sites actually follow it to a different extent...

Comment: Find potential models you want to buy; then check the hardware on them to see whether it's compatible with your Linux distro.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [hardware page](http://wiki.debian.org/Hardware) on the Debian Wiki, but it's unfortunately rather sparse. However, you can use lists from other Linux vendors as well:

- [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/)
- [RedHat](https://hardware.redhat.com/)
- [SuSE](http://en.opensuse.org/Portal%3aHardware)
- Maybe [Gentoo](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Index%3aHardware) [link was down when I was writing this, and so is archive.org.]
- [LinuxQuestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/hcl/)
- Linux journal has a [list of lists](http://www.linuxjournal.com/supportedhardware).

You may have to jump through a few initial hoops, if e.g., you need to install a newer kernel than Wheezy ships.

You can of course also look for models, and put *modelname Linux* into Google, and you'll typically find how well it works with Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a Thinkpad E series 13". As long as you make sure Ethernet and Wi-fi are supported, the rest should work as expected, as long as you go for a model without discrete graphics. I use a E330 and Linux works perfectly on it, although the CPU (i3 Ivy Bridge) is not ULV, so not quite ultrabook-ish.